# How to update particular image related data using doctrine entity with one to many relationship in Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, image-upload

I have two entities (namely Book, Image) having OneToMany relationship between them, i.e. One book can have more than one images.
Now when I am trying to edit the details of the book, how can I do edit for any particular image for that particular book?

More clearly if I say, I want to alter only one particular image out of all the images previously uploaded. Can anyone help me on this please?

Below are my entities and forms.

```
/**
* @ORM\Table(name="books")
* @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Library\MainBundle\Entity\BookRepository")
*/
class Book
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="subject", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $subject;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="isbn", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $isbn;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="Description", type="text")
 */
private $description;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="books")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 **/
private $category;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="bookpublishers")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="publisher_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 **/
private $publisher;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="bookauthors")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="book_author")
 **/
private $author;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="BookReview", mappedBy="bookreview", cascade={"all"})
 **/
private $reviews;

/**
 * @var string $image
 * @Assert\File( maxSize = "1024k", mimeTypesMessage = "Please upload a valid Image")
 * @ORM\Column(name="image", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $image;

/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Image", mappedBy="book", cascade={"all"})
**/
private $pictures;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $imageName;

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set name
 *
 * @param string $name
 * @return Book
 */
public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get name
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}

/**
 * Set subject
 *
 * @param string $subject
 * @return Book
 */
public function setSubject($subject)
{
    $this->subject = $subject;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get subject
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getSubject()
{
    return $this->subject;
}

/**
 * Set isbn
 *
 * @param string $isbn
 * @return Book
 */
public function setIsbn($isbn)
{
    $this->isbn = $isbn;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get isbn
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getIsbn()
{
    return $this->isbn;
}

/**
 * Set description
 *
 * @param string $description
 * @return Book
 */
public function setDescription($description)
{
    $this->description = $description;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get description
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getDescription()
{
    return $this->description;
}

/**
 * Set category
 *
 * @param \Library\MainBundle\Entity\Category $category
 * @return Book
 */
public function setCategory(Category $category = null)
{
    $this->category = $category;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get category
 *
 * @return \Library\MainBundle\Entity\Category 
 */
public function getCategory()
{
    return $this->category;
}

/**
 * Set publisher
 *
 * @param \Library\MainBundle\Entity\User $publisher
 * @return Book
 */
public function setPublisher(User $publisher = null)
{
    $this->publisher = $publisher;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get publisher
 *
 * @return \Library\MainBundle\Entity\User 
 */
    public function getPublisher()
{
    return $this->publisher;
}

/**
 * Add author
 *
 * @param \Library\MainBundle\Entity\User $author
 * @return Book
 */
public function addAuthor(User $author)
{
    $this->author[] = $author;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove author
 *
 * @param \Library\MainBundle\Entity\User $author
 */
public function removeAuthor(User $author)
{
    $this->author->removeElement($author);
}

/**
 * Get author
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getAuthor()
{
    return $this->author;
}

/**
 * Set author
 *
 * @return User
 */
public function setAuthor(User $author)
{
    $this->author[] = $author;
}


/**
 * Add reviews
 *
 * @param \Library\MainBundle\Entity\BookReview $reviews
 * @return Book
 */
public function addReview(BookReview $reviews)
{
    $this->reviews[] = $reviews;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove reviews
 *
 * @param \Library\MainBundle\Entity\BookReview $reviews
 */
public function removeReview(BookReview $reviews)
{
    $this->reviews->removeElement($reviews);
}

/**
 * Get reviews
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getReviews()
{
    return $this->reviews;
}

public function getFullImagePath() {
    return null === $this->image ? null : $this->getUploadRootDir(). $this->image;
}

protected function getUploadRootDir() {
    // the absolute directory path where uploaded documents should be saved
    return $this->getTmpUploadRootDir().$this->getId()."/";
}

protected function getTmpUploadRootDir() {
    // the absolute directory path where uploaded documents should be saved
    return __DIR__ . '/../../../../web/upload/books/';
}

/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist()
 * @ORM\PreUpdate()
 */
public function uploadImage() {
    // the file property can be empty if the field is not required
    if (null === $this->image) {
        return;
    }
    $tempImageName = time() . '_' .$this->image->getClientOriginalName();
    if(!$this->id){
        $this->setImageName($this->image->getClientOriginalName());
        $this->image->move($this->getTmpUploadRootDir(), $this->image->getClientOriginalName());
    }else{
        $this->image->move($this->getUploadRootDir(), $tempImageName);
        unlink($this->getUploadRootDir().$this->getImageName());
    }

    $this->setImage($tempImageName);

}

 /**
 * @ORM\PostPersist()
 */
public function moveImage()
{
    if (null === $this->image) {
        return;
    }
    if(!is_dir($this->getUploadRootDir())){
        mkdir($this->getUploadRootDir());
    }
    copy($this->getTmpUploadRootDir().$this->getImageName(), $this->getFullImagePath());
    unlink($this->getTmpUploadRootDir().$this->getImageName());
}

/**
 * @ORM\PreRemove()
 */
public function removeImage()
{
    unlink($this->getFullImagePath());
    rmdir($this->getUploadRootDir());
}


/**
 * Set image
 *
 * @param string $image
 * @return Book
 */
public function setImage($image)
{
    $this->image = $image;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get image
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getImage()
{
    return $this->image;
}

/**
 * Set image
 *
 * @param string $image
 * @return Book
 */
public function setImageName($image)
{
    $this->imageName = $image;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get image
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getImageName()
{
    return $this->imageName;
}

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->author = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->reviews = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->pictures = new ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * Add pictures
 *
 * @param \Library\MainBundle\Entity\Image $pictures
 * @return Book
 */
public function addPicture(Image $pictures)
{
    $this->pictures[] = $pictures;
    $pictures->setBook($this);
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove pictures
 *
 * @param \Library\MainBundle\Entity\Image $pictures
 */
public function removePicture(Image $pictures)
{
    $this->pictures->removeElement($pictures);
}

/**
 * Get pictures
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getPictures()
{
    return $this->pictures;
}

}
```

Image Entity (Image.php)

```
/**
* Image
*
* @ORM\Table(name="book_images")
* @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Library\MainBundle\Entity\ImageRepository")
*/
class Image
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 * @Assert\File( maxSize = "1024k", mimeTypesMessage = "Please upload a valid Image")
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Book", inversedBy="pictures")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="book_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 **/
private $book;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $imageName;


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set name
 *
 * @param string $name
 * @return Image
 */
public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get name
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}

/**
 * Set book
 *
 * @param \Library\MainBundle\Entity\Book $book
 * @return Image
 */
public function setBook(Book $book)
{
    $this->book = $book;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get book
 *
 * @return \Library\MainBundle\Entity\Book 
 */
public function getBook()
{
    return $this->book;
}

/**
 * Set image
 *
 * @param string $image
 * @return Book
 */
public function setImageName($image)
{
    $this->imageName = $image;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get image
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getImageName()
{
    return $this->imageName;
}

public function getFullImagePath() {
    return null === $this->name ? null : $this->getUploadRootDir(). $this->name;
}

protected function getUploadRootDir() {
    // the absolute directory path where uploaded documents should be saved
    return $this->getTmpUploadRootDir().$this->getBook()->getId()."/";
}

protected function getTmpUploadRootDir() {
    // the absolute directory path where uploaded documents should be saved
    return __DIR__ . '/../../../../web/upload/books/';
}

/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist()
 * @ORM\PreUpdate()
 */
public function uploadImage() {
    // the file property can be empty if the field is not required
    if (null === $this->name) {
        return;
    }
    $tempImageName = time() . '_' .$this->name->getClientOriginalName();
    if(!$this->getBook()->getId()){
        $this->setImageName($this->name->getClientOriginalName());
        $this->name->move($this->getTmpUploadRootDir(), $this->name->getClientOriginalName());
    }else{
        $this->name->move($this->getUploadRootDir(), $tempImageName);
        unlink($this->getUploadRootDir().$this->getImageName());
    }

    $this->setName($tempImageName);

}

 /**
 * @ORM\PostPersist()
 */
public function moveImage()
{
    if (null === $this->name) {
        return;
    }
    if(!is_dir($this->getUploadRootDir())){
        mkdir($this->getUploadRootDir());
    }
    copy($this->getTmpUploadRootDir().$this->getImageName(), $this->getFullImagePath());
    unlink($this->getTmpUploadRootDir().$this->getImageName());
}

/**
 * @ORM\PreRemove()
 */
public function removeImage()
{
    unlink($this->getFullImagePath());
    rmdir($this->getUploadRootDir());
}

}
```

My Forms :
BookType.php

```
namespace Library\MainBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Library\MainBundle\Entity\Role;
use Library\MainBundle\Entity\Image;

class BookType extends AbstractType
{

/**
 * @var \Library\MainBundle\Entity\Role
 */
protected $publisherrole;

/**
 * @var \Library\MainBundle\Entity\Role
 */
protected $authorrole;

public function __construct (Role $publisherRole, Role $authorRole)
{
    $this->publisherrole = $publisherRole;
    $this->authorrole = $authorRole;
}

/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name', 'text', array('label' => 'book.label.name',
                                    'attr' => array('class' => 'element text medium')))
        ->add('subject', 'text', array('label' => 'book.label.subject',
                                        'attr' => array('class' => 'element text medium')))
        ->add('isbn', 'text', array('label'=> 'book.label.isbn',
                                    'attr' => array('class' => 'element text medium')))
        ->add('description', 'textarea', array('label' => 'book.label.description',
                                                'attr' => array('class' => 'element textarea medium')))
        ->add('category', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'LibraryMainBundle:Category',
                'property' => 'name',
                "label" => 'book.label.category',
                "attr" => array('class' => 'element select medium')))
        ->add('publisher', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'LibraryMainBundle:User',
                'property' => 'name',
                'label' => 'book.label.publisher',
                'choices' => $this->publisherrole->getUser(),
                'attr' => array('class' => 'element select medium')
            ))
        ->add('author', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'LibraryMainBundle:User',
                'property' => 'name',
                'label' => 'book.label.author',
                'choices' => $this->authorrole->getUser(),
                'multiple' => 'true',
                'attr' => array('class' => 'element select medium')
            ))
        ->add('image', 'file', array('label' => 'book.label.coverpic',
                                    'attr' => array('class' => 'element textarea medium'),
                                    'data_class' => null
            ))
        ->add("pictures", 'collection', array(
        'type'=>new FileType(),
        'allow_add'=>true,
                'by_reference' => true,
        'data'=>array(new Image(),
                                new Image()
                    )
    ))
        ->add("save", "submit", array('label' => 'book.button.save'));
}

/**
 * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
 */
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Library\MainBundle\Entity\Book'
    ));
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return 'library_mainbundle_book';
}
}
```

FileType.php

```
namespace Library\MainBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class FileType extends AbstractType
{

 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    return $builder->add("name", "file");
}

public function getName()
{
    return "filetype";
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class'=>'Library\MainBundle\Entity\Image',
        'csrf_protection'=>true,
        'csrf_field_name'=>'_token',
        'intention'=>'file'
    ));
}
}
```

Please let me know if anything more required from my end.

Comment: just to clearify: You simple want to delete images that were previously set, or?

Comment: Yes I want to delete those images from the folder as well as update the existing DB table rows for Image entity with the new image names.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work at the moment ? Why you have `image` and `pictures` ?

Comment: @Hpatoio, When I am trying to edit the book details, and upload the images for pictures field, it adds new rows in the image entity instead of updating the existing ones.

image is for storing one image that will be stored in the book entity while pictures is the one to many relation between book and image entity. i.e. Whatever images uploaded in teh pictures field are for the image entity (i.e. book_images table, Please for more reference, see ORM annotation in image entity at the top.)